# liquibase diffChangeLog does not reflect any changes

Tags: liquibase

I´ve been able to generate a ChangeLog from my current database using the following command:

```
Liquibase --driver=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver --classpath=C:\i2S-devenv\apps\hsqldb-2.2.9\lib\hsqldb.jar --changeLogFile=c:\i2S-devenv\changelog.xml --url="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9901/test_db" generateChangeLog
```

Now, i've made some changes in the database (drop tables) and i want to update my changelog to reflect those changes. I've execute the following command:

```
Liquibase --driver=org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver --classpath=C:\i2S-devenv\apps\hsqldb-2.2.9\lib\hsqldb.jar --changeLogFile=c:\i2S-devenv\changelog2.xml  --url="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9901/test_db" diffChangeLog --referenceUrl="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9901/test_db"
```

What is wrong with this approach. I can not see any differences in the Changelog.

Thanks.

Tiago

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the database to itself. In order to compare two databases, you have to have the --url argument and the --referenceUrl be different databases.

```
         --url="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9901/test_db"
--referenceUrl="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost:9901/test_db"
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for you reply. That means i can not compare the same database in two different moments, right? If i want to see the differences between the same database instance in two different moments (begin and end of the day, for example) i can not use liquibase?

Comment: Correct - that is not a problem that Liquibase is designed to address.